# Why don't I have find_element_by_blablabla?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation, findelement

I was using **Selenium** to automate browser things and I my WebDriver object doesn't have the attributes find_element_by_link_text for example.

It only has:

```py
find_element()
```

or:

```py
find-elements()
```

No other methods starting with find. Is this due to  my WebDriver?

I was using:

- **Web Driver:** Chrome
- **Version:** 103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the [Selenium Python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), first you need to import By :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then, depending on how you want to locate a certain element, these are the following available attributes:

```
ID = "id"
NAME = "name"
XPATH = "xpath"
LINK_TEXT = "link text"
PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
TAG_NAME = "tag name"
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

And the syntax to locate elements using the above mentioned attributes is the following:

```
find_element(By.ID, "id")
find_element(By.NAME, "name")
find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "link text")
find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "partial link text")
find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tag name")
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name")
find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css selector")
```

I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

The Newer Versions of Selenium in Python Are Using the By Module

Try something like

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    webdriver # Lets assume it exists
    oneElement=webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
    youWanted=find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "link text")
    listOfMatchingElements=webdriver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
```

The other "find_elements_by_*" are old and not longer used
For Reference look here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html